# Ansible run the same role multiple times with different vars file included

Tags: ansible

I have a role which I would like to run multiple times with different vars files, I am currently doing the following:

```
- hosts: localhost
  pre_tasks:
      include_vars: "vars/vars1.yml"
  roles:
    - my_role

- hosts: localhost
  pre_tasks:
      include_vars: "vars/vars2.yml"
  roles:
    - my_role
```

Is there a less boilerplate way to do this? I know it is [possible to parameterise roles](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles) but I can't find anything in the ansible documentation regarding running a role multiple times and calling a different `include_vars` each time.

Answer (score 1):

i wanted to do something similar a while back and i ended up having two groups in my inventory

```
[group1]
localhost1

[group2]
localhost2
```

and then in group_vars i had different values. In your case that would be

```
# file: group_vars/group1/main.yml
include_file: vars/vars1.yml
```

and

```
# file: group_vars/group2/main.yml
include_file: vars/vars2.yml
```

Then, you can modify your playbook to something like this

```
- hosts: all
  pre_tasks:
      include_vars: "{{ include_file }}"
  roles:
    - my_role
```

and finally, execute your playbook for both groups

```
ansible-playbook pb.yml -l group1,group2
```

and it should take care of both instalations